# How to align number in a column in python

Tags: python, arrays, formatting

I want to align the number in my output file, this is my code:

```
tabfil=sys.argv[1]
n=int(sys.argv[2])
n1=int(sys.argv[3])
n2=int(sys.argv[4])
n3=int(sys.argv[5])

arr=np.genfromtxt(tabfil,usecols=n)
arr1=np.genfromtxt(tabfil,usecols=n1)
arr2=np.genfromtxt(tabfil,usecols=n2)
arr3=np.genfromtxt(tabfil,usecols=n3)

arr=arr-arr1-arr2+arr3
arr2=arr1+arr2-arr3
for i in range(len(arr)):
print(arr[i],'  ',arr2[i])
```

My output is:

```
0.0    0.0
-1.977    6.503
0.788    0.517
0.087    0.034
3.181    2.432
0.794    0.345
-0.395    4.097
-0.044    0.859
1.529    2.47
-0.068    6.334
```

But I want:

```
 0.0        0.0
-1.977      6.503
 0.788      0.517
 0.087      0.034
 .....      ......
```

Where is my mistake? I should define some format?

Comment: You can use Pretty printer utility check https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: [PrettyTable](https://pypi.org/project/PrettyTable/) can be helpful. or just do it with python string formatting (tutorial to [different methods of string formatting](http://zetcode.com/python/fstring/) on zetcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make an assumption that both of your arrays must be same length. If that us the case then you can find out the widest integer in your array and then use that in conjuction with rjust and ljust string formatting:

```
arr = [34,334,343,33456476,58567,575543,3543]
arr2 = [134321,24234,2434,23424,244,23424, 342]

widest_number = 0

for number in arr:
    if len(str(number))>widest_number:
        widest_number = len(str(number))

for i in range(len(arr)):
    print("{}   {}".format(str(arr[i]).rjust(widest_number), str(arr2[i]).ljust(widest_number)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, exactly they have the same lenght. That is really useful way to correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple python formatting to achieve your goal.

Instead of

`print(arr[i],'  ',arr2[i])`

use something like

`print('{:< 6g} {:< 6g}'.format(arr[i], arr2[i]))`

More details about string formatting you can check here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

or here - https://pyformat.info/#number